# What novel trilogy has a mostly-grayscale picture of a hooded person on each cover?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I saw a picture of a novel trilogy on 9gag, and each book’s cover had a person in a hooded top pictured from the back. His face was partially visible as he was looking back. All 3 books had similar cover, though the person might change the pose slightly.

The person on the cover was pictured in grayscale except for some part which had a few colors like orange, green and blue. The background was white in color.

I don't quite remember, but the author's name had the word 'Freed' in it. The title was in English.

Anybody has any idea which novel is it?

Comment: What was the language of the novel? What was the country you saw this in? When did you see the covers?

Comment: English was the language used for the title

Comment: Based on your comment below my answer, I'm guessing this was "urban fantasy"?

Comment: what year did you see this?  was it in a shop?

Comment: I saw the pic on 9gag.
@Richard: Urban Fantasy it is not. I have mentioned, background was completely white... no design or patterns

Comment: https://parchmentplace.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/the-black-magician-tilogy.png

Comment: @Richard: Nope, not the one you mentioned in link. From the looks of the person in hooded top on the cover, it seemed to have been set in current time period or maybe future.

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri - modern or futuristic but not urban? Can you describe the hooded figure any better. Also, where/when did you see the picture on 9Gag?

Comment: David Freed doesnt really match on Google... the covers you describe sound a lot like Brent Weeks covers, but modern fantasy they aint.

Comment: @Radhil - This sort of thing? http://aidanmoher.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/night-angel-trilogy-by-brent-weeks.jpeg

Comment: @Richard - exactly that, yup

Comment: It'll be interesting to see just how many different answers this gets...

Comment: especially considering how common/cliche the hooded figure is on fantasy book covers.

Comment: [Legends of the red sun has hoods](https://www.goodreads.com/series/49430-legends-of-the-red-sun), but doesn't match most of the rest, so it's an unlikely candidate.

Comment: How long ago did you see this? Do you not have access to your browser history if it was recent?

Comment: same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238210/name-of-a-fantasy-book-where-male-character-finds-a-magic-absorbing-artifact

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: Blockquote]

Do you mean *The Night Angel Trilogy* by Brent Weeks? I saw a post about it on 9gag a few days past. The covers are mostly white, and each show a hooded man in black clothing in various poses, with swirls of color.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: @Angrist - your post doesn't quite answer the question. The OP has mentioned that the person on the cover is pictured from _back_, and also the picture was gray-scale, i.e. black n white.

Comment: @ash_k29 He only showed one of the 3 books. But one of the covers matches the description: http://blog.patrickrothfuss.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Weeks_Night-Angel.jpg

Comment: Oh. that's great. The image you shared clears doubt. But still there's the small issue of _"freed"_.....

Comment: @Lyrion - And also there's the grayscale part missing...

Comment: @ash_k29 Just saying that out all of these trilogies, non has any grayscale part. Nor are they by authers with "freed" in it. But 1 of the covers does match the description

Comment: THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER.... YIPEE YAY KAY....
THANKS MAN THANKS....

Answer (score 13):

The Black Magician trilogy by Trudi Canavan?

1. [The Magician's Guild](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Magicians-Guild-Black-Magician-Trilogy/dp/1841499609)

   [image]
2. [The Novice](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Novice-Book-Black-Magician-Trilogy/dp/1841499617)

   [image]
3. [The High Lord](http://www.amazon.co.uk/High-Lord-Black-Magician-Trilogy/dp/1841499625)

   [image]

Comment: I was thinking of this as well that's why I asked for a time frame :)

Comment: No, this is not the book I am searching.

Answer (score 9):

Your description reminded me of this novel series.

[image]

Comment: Nope, this wasn't the novel. From the looks of the person in hooded top on the cover, it seemed to have been set in current time period or maybe future.

Answer (score 9):

Reminds me of The Left Hand of God trilogy by Paul Hoffman (his name obviously doesn't have Freed in it though)

[image: The Left Hand of God]

[image: The Last Four Things]

[image: The Beating of His Wings]

Excellent original series though I struggled to get through the last one - binge read them though so maybe overdosed ;-)

Answer (score 6):

The Painted Man by Peter V. Brett?

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Painted_Man]

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: @Wikis is correct, we really need more information.